# Does size of unrelated SQL tables affect each others performance

Tags: php, mysql, api, bigdata

I have an api written in php, that generally selects from / inserts to 5 MySQL tables of size 10K rows.

Each api request is logged into separate table of size 10M rows (growing by 100K rows per day).

The api only inserts into the big table. This table is used for statistics / error reporting and is never selected from or joined to another table in any api request.

Can size of the big table at some point slow down unrelated operations in those other tables?

Comment: Be more specific. What is your exact scenario? Unrelated is unrelated. However, your description implies that yet there's some relation between some of the operations in your code. Describe the exact problem supported with code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have table A and table B, which are completely unrelated, then A's size will not affect the speed of selections from B or insertions to B. However, in your case they are not completely unrelated if the big table can be found in the same database running on the same computer as the others, so, if you issue many commands related to the big table, then due to the concurrency, commands regarding other tables might become slower. If this problem will occur at all, then it will be a slow process, you will observe it way before it becomes severe. As a result, I believe you should not worry about this now, but keep in mind the options you need to consider if the problem materializes.